# What is the correct Date Format String for Month DD, YYYY to use in Powershell

Tags: powershell, datetime

I have not been able to figure out the date format to detect the date string of `August 20, 2022` I have attempted using this format `month dd, yyyy` to detect it however it is not working.  I have several dates in my file formatted in this manner.  Currently my script is missing these and I need to first figure out how to detect these.

In the below code I have a date format array I pass into `TryParseExact` named `$formatsDelimited`.  All of my date formats work except for the one I stated above.  It is the last format string I added to the array (granted this one is not a delimited format but nonetheless ... ).

## The code

```
$formatsDelimited = [string[]]@('M_d_yyyy','M_dd_yyyy','MM_d_yyyy','MM_dd_yyyy','M_d_yy','M_dd_yy','MM_d_yy','MM_dd_yy'
                               ,'M/d/yyyy','M/dd/yyyy','MM/d/yyyy','MM/dd/yyyy','M/d/yy','M/dd/yy','MM/d/yy','MM/dd/yy'
                               ,'M-d-yyyy','M-dd-yyyy','MM-d-yyyy','MM-dd-yyyy','M-d-yy','M-dd-yy','MM-d-yy','MM-dd-yy'
                               ,'M.d.yyyy','M.dd.yyyy','MM.d.yyyy','MM.dd.yyyy','M.d.yy','M.dd.yy','MM.d.yy','MM.dd.yy'
                               ,'month dd, yyyy')

@(
  'January 21, 2019'
  '05_11_2022'
  'NULL'
  '6/15/2020 6/16/2020'
  '7/'
  '09.01.2022'
  '02262021'
  '05/04/2021'
  'ES'
  '10/11'
  '10/15'
  '03/202022'
  '10202022'
  'Last week'
  '10/06//2022'
  '3/8/22'
  'July 28, 2022'
  'August 20, 2022'
) | 
ForEach-Object {
    # Variable for date
    [datetime]$dt = New-Object DateTime

    # Check that directory name could be parsed to DateTime
    if ([DateTime]::TryParseExact($_, $formatsDelimited,
                                [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture,
                                [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None,
                                [ref]$dt))
    {
        $_
    } else {
        Write-Warning "Unrecognized timestamp: $_"
    }

}
```

## Output

```
WARNING: Unrecognized timestamp: January 21, 2019
05_11_2022
WARNING: Unrecognized timestamp: NULL
WARNING: Unrecognized timestamp: 6/15/2020 6/16/2020
WARNING: Unrecognized timestamp: 7/
09.01.2022
WARNING: Unrecognized timestamp: 02262021
05/04/2021
WARNING: Unrecognized timestamp: ES
WARNING: Unrecognized timestamp: 10/11
WARNING: Unrecognized timestamp: 10/15
WARNING: Unrecognized timestamp: 03/202022
WARNING: Unrecognized timestamp: 10202022
WARNING: Unrecognized timestamp: Last week
WARNING: Unrecognized timestamp: 10/06//2022
3/8/22
WARNING: Unrecognized timestamp: July 28, 2022
WARNING: Unrecognized timestamp: August 20, 2022
```

Comment: you can use `'MMMM dd, yyyy'` as format to parse that date

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings  Powershell is written in the Net Library and any c# code can be converted to PS.  When writing PS scripts I often first write in c# and then translate.  The answer I gave yesterday came from c#.  I often in c# use multiple formats with TryParseExact.

Comment: It's just that easy.  I looked and did NOT find on the Internet a four digit method to represent the full month name.  Must have missed that one.

Comment: When you can't find in PS then try c#

Comment: See [Custom date and time format strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). @jdweng, this has nothing to do with _C#_ per se; these are _.NET APIs_, accessible to _any_ .NET-based language, including PowerShell.

Comment: @mklement0 : When you perform searches on the web using c# in search string helps get the answers.

Comment: @jdweng, while that is probably true, it is only _incidentally_ true, because C# _happens to be_ the most popular .NET language (a status that, at least hypothetically, can change over time). Even if _pragmatically_ speaking using "C#" as the search term may get you the information you need, knowing the difference between C# and .NET is important. To search the latter's documentation, start at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `MMMM dd, yyyy` to parse dates in that format:

```bash
'July 28, 2022', 'August 20, 2022' | ForEach-Object {
    [datetime]::ParseExact($_, 'MMMM dd, yyyy', [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
}
```

As aside, `Get-Date` has no problems interpreting dates with this format:

```bash
Get-Date 'July 28, 2022'
```

Comment: I was originally using other methods to detect dates but then I found they also would find 10/20 as a date just to name one of the many issues I encountered.  There were just way too many `Not actual Dates` being found by other date tools that I ended up having to strip it all out and go with a manual approach.

Comment: Nicely done; the caveat with respect to `Get-Date` is that it - regrettably - first interprets its argument _culture-sensitively_. For instance, `Get-Date '10.5.2023'` with culture `es-AR` in effect, yields 10 May 2023, whereas with culture `en-US` in effect it yields 5 October 2023. Only using an always-culture-invariant `[datetime]` _cast_ avoids this. See the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: Won't this code give an exception when the date is not valid?  That is why I use TryParseExact yesterday on OPs first posting.

Comment: @jdweng of course it will, I used `ParseExact` just to explicitly answer OP's question, "What is the correct Date Format String for Month DD, YYYY"